# jQuery .last() picking 2 values instead of one

Tags: jquery

I have images displaying in a modal and an upload image function. When I upload new images, they append to the last existing image and that last existing image's background should go red.

For some reason what is happening is that when I upload 2 images at once, the last existing record goes red as it should, but so does the first appended image. I don't understand why the first uploaded image is also having the CSS applied.

```
   $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $( ".img-box" ).last().css("background", "red");
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $( "#gallery-body" ).append(`
                <div class="col-md-3 img-box">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="" name="pics[]" value="${file.name}" data-id="" />
                    <label for="" style="background-image: url(uploads/${file.name})">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                    </label>
                </div>

               `);
    // progress bar
```

HTML output:

```
<div class="col-md-3 img-box" style="background: red;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="image_16" name="pics[]" value="wave-2211925_640.jpg" data-id="image_16">
    <label for="image_16" style="background-image: url(uploads/wave-2211925_640.jpg)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 img-box" style="background: red;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="" name="pics[]" value="dzone.jpg" data-id="">
    <label for="" style="background-image: url(uploads/dzone.jpg)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post output HTML after upload 2 x images?

Comment: @ProEvilz, not sure if that is what you are looking for but I updated my question with the html output

Comment: If I prepend instead of append, I don't get the same issue.

Comment: What happens if you move the `.last()` line of code **after** the `$.each()` ?

Comment: I assume it's because you have a `.img-box` existing first, which then gets the red BG applied, but then on the next iteration you get an additional `.img-box` DIV added to the dom, which then becomes the last element. So both are last at some point in time since it technically gets added 1 by 1

Comment: Hmm. Is there a way around this or should I just prepend instead? Now that I think about it, using prepend would probably be better because then the newly uploaded images are shown first instead of being sent right to the end of the image display. The user then would have to go hunt for them instead of just seeing them right at the beginning.

Comment: If I move .last() after $.each() the same thing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single `.img-box` is last item of `#gallery-body` container. Thus, second calling of script will set red background for first `.img-box` (see snippet below).

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".img-box").last().css("background", "red");
  $("#gallery-body").append(
    "<div class=\"img-box\">" +
    "content" +
    "</div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery-body">
</div>
<button>Add new item</button>
```

If you want to only last item will be red, you could use CSS:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#gallery-body").append(
    "<div class =\"img-box\">" +
    "content" +
    "</div>");
});
```

```css
.img-box:last-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery-body">
</div>
<button>Add new item</button>
```

Comment: Aha, niince one!